# How to see the contents of a file be written by BUfferbytes

Tags: java, bytebuffer

WHen I use bufferbyte to input say integer 1 into the file, as .txt file,

```
Filechanel fc
    (buffer.putInt(1))
    fc.write(buffer).
```

when I open it with text editor, it does not appear to be 1 there, but it could be read by buffer correctly. But if I input character such as 'a', 'b' into the file, it appears well.

Is it nature that, when I input integers with bytebuffer, I cannot open it and see it clearly with eyes.

Comment: `0x01` is not a printable character, is that your question?

Answer (score 0):

In order to see the integer you write to the file, you must first convert it to readable characters. For example, the integer 20000 is different from the string "20000". The integer is represented as 4 bytes in the file where as the individual characters that make up the readable string consist of at least 5 (in this example). Therefore, what you don't see when you write the integer value to the text file is the text editor trying to interpret the 4 bytes that make up the integer as 4 ascii characters (which may or may not be visible).

Answer (score 0):

All computer files everywhere are just a sequence of bits and bytes.

Humans have come up with a way to represent human readable characters with bit sequences. These are known as character sets or character encodings. A very basic one is [ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII).

For example, the English upper-case character `A` is represented with the binary value

```
100 0001
```

the decimal value

```
65
```

or the hex value

```
41
```

When you write

```
(buffer.putInt(1))
fc.write(buffer) // assuming you've positioned the ByteBuffer
```

you're writing the decimal value `1` as binary to the file. The decimal value 1, as an `int`, in binary, is

```
00000000 00000000 00000000 00000001
```

since an `int` is 4 bytes.

When you open the file with a text editor (or any editor), it will see 4 bytes and try to give you the textual representation.

Comment: SO detailed, I really appreciate it!!

Comment: @user3495562 Consider upvoting and accepting good answers. You've asked a few now, but don't seem to have checked any as accepted.

Comment: I am new here, where should I say I accept the answer?

Comment: @user3495562 On the left of the answer there are arrows and a checkmark. You check the checkmark to accept an answer and indicate that it answered your question to your satisfaction. You can upvote if it was good and/or helpful. You downvote if it was not useful or wrong.